# What does this mean in this context で、幽が引っ張っていくオチか >> So she is the one pulling the punch line?

Tags: meaning, japanese-to-english, conversations

context is You (MC-as Kensuke in this dialogue) is speaking with 2 subordinate of a general /shogun (一葉 Kazuha) about her strange behavior recently (Hifumi and Koi)They're secretly following Kazuha and her subordinate (幽) Yuu

Hifumi......確かにそれは、公方様にしては珍しい

相変わらず一葉たちに気取られない距離を取って尾行しつつ.俺の話を聞いたーニ三は、ふむ、と小さな声を上げてみせた。

Kensuke : 俺がいない時の一葉って、どんな感じなの?

Koi: 私たちが京にいる間だけの話ですが……剣丞さまがいらっしゃる時と変わらないと思いますよ。剣丞さまの所が双葉さまか、久遠さまに変わるだけで

Kensuke:で、幽が引っ張っていくオチか >> This is the part I don't understand ( my guess is "So she (Yuu) is the one who's pulling the punchline ?>)

Hifumi: まあ、公方さまにあそこまで出来る方なんてそうそういないだろうしね

If you can please show me your English TL at the part I don't understand thanks .I don't know my guess about the punch line is correct or not

Answer (score 3):

This オチ is "(unfavorable but easily expected) outcome" rather than "punchline". In particular, ～のがオチだ is a common set phrase that means "Surely it'll end up (something bad)" or "(Something bad) is all you can expect". See the second definition [here](https://jisho.org/word/%E8%90%BD%E3%81%A1), and the following monolingual dictionary definition.

> #### [落ち](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%90%BD%E3%81%A1/)
>
> ３ 行き着くところ。結末。
>
> ㋐落語などで、しゃれや語呂合わせなどで話の終わりを締めくくる部分。下げ。また、一般に、話の効果的な結末。「この話には落ちがついている」
> ㋑**物事について予想されるよくない成り行き**。「断られるのが落ちだ」

Thus:

> で、幽が引っ張っていくオチか
> So, the result is that Yū takes the lead, huh?
> And it (always) ends up with Yū taking the lead, huh?

(I'm not 100% certain about the meaning of this 引っ張る, so please change that part according to the context. It could mean "to (physically) drag her out" or something.)